# JOINS between 7 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have got alot of help in my previous post, which lets me understand the Database model better. I have read tutorials and explainations about JOINS, but i can't seem to figure it out, hereby my database model;

```
    ***Person***        ***DrivingLicense***  ***DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes***
ID                  ID                    ID
Name                ExpiryDate            DrivingLicense_ID
                    Person_ID             LicenseType_ID

***LicenseTypes***  ***LicenseTypeVehicleTypes*** ***VehicleTypes***    ***Vehicles***
ID                  ID                            ID                    ID
LicenseType         LicenseType_ID                VehicleType           Make
                    VehicleType_ID                                      Model
                                                                        VehicleType_ID
                                                                        Person_ID

Person: (1, 'Person1'), (2, 'Person2');
DrivingLicense: (1, '2015-01-01', 1), (2, '2015-10-01', 2);
VehicleTypes: (1, 'Car'), (2, 'Motorbike');
LicenseTypes: (1, 'Car'), (2, 'Motorbike');
Vehicles: (1, 'Ford', 'Focus', 1), (2, 'Chevrolet', 'Caprice', 1), (3, 'Ducati', 'Multistrada', 2);
LicenseTypeVehicleTypes: (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2);
DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes: (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2);
```

Now i want to run a SELECT query, which basically i want to link the tables:

```
PersonID.ID -> DrivingLicense.ID
DLLT.DrivingLicense_ID -> DrivingLicense.ID
DLLT.LicenseType_ID -> LicenseTypes.ID
LTVT.LicenseType_ID -> LicenseTypes.ID
LTVT.VehicleType_ID -> VehicleTypes.ID
Vehicles.Type_ID -> Vehicletypes.ID
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM Person
INNER JOIN DrivingLicense.ID ON Person.ID = DrivingLicense.ID
INNER JOIN DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes ON DrivingLicense.ID = DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes.DrivingLicense_ID
INNER JOIN LicenseTypes ON DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes.LicenseType_ID = LicenseTypes.ID
INNER JOIN LicenseTypeVehicleTypes ON LicenseTypes.ID = LicenseTypeVehicleTypes
INNER JOIN VehicleTypes ON LicenseTypeVehicleTypes.VehicleType_ID = VehicleTypes.ID
WHERE x=y AND x=y
```

I think i am starting off the wrong way and making Rookie mistakes, i have tried starting with an OUTER JOIN, to get results even if they are blank.

Do i start off the wrong foot, do i need to turn the steps around?

Maybe to clear some things up:

Before this page where i run the query, i have 2 searchfields, 1 is unique for person, 1 is unique for vehicle.

Based on these 2 values, i am checking if they match (Check if the person indeed is the owner of the value). So far so good.

After that, i want to check, based on my license type, vehicle type and Expiry date of my license, if the person is valid to drive the vehicle. A person with a license to drive a scooter, may not drive a car.

Therefore i have adjusted my database setup with help from here, i've read the differende between INNER, OUTER, CROSS, LEFT JOINS, etc. But i keep searching for the missing link. I think some logic is still missing.

How can i gather the info i need with the apprioriate JOINS? I want to avoid the situation that I'm using:

```
SELECT table1, table2 FROM column1, column2
```

For example.

The following query gives me double results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM RijbewijsTypes
LEFT JOIN RijbewijstypeVoertuigtype ON RijbewijstypeVoertuigtype.RijbewijstypeID = RijbewijsTypes.ID
LEFT JOIN RijbewijsRijbewijsType ON RijbewijsRijbewijsType.RijbewijstypeID
LEFT JOIN Rijbewijs ON Rijbewijs.ID = RijbewijsRijbewijsType.RijbewijsID
LEFT JOIN Persoon ON Persoon.ID = Rijbewijs.PersoonID
LEFT JOIN Voertuig ON Voertuig.PersoonID = Persoon.ID
LEFT JOIN Merk ON Merk.ID = Voertuig.Merk
LEFT JOIN Type ON Merk.Type = Type.ID
WHERE Persoon.BSNNummer =  '20230913'
AND Voertuig.Kenteken =  'NH-UN-78'
```

Comment: Yeeaah! `DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes`!

Comment: Does the query fail? Error? 0 results? Too many results? What happens?

Comment: You have a mistake in your join statement: there's an additional =

Comment: 1) Inner joins will only return data if records are in both tables being joined. 2) Left joins will include records from the first table and not the second 3) Right joins will include records from the second table and not the first.  4) Full Outer joins will return all records from both tables, regardless of joins.  Use of where clause can negate the joins, so don't use them at first.  If you need to limit the data from the table put the limits on the join `from A inner join b on a.id = b.id and b.value='No'`  try full outer joins without a where clause and go from there...

Comment: You join `person.ID` on `DrivingLicence.ID`. You should join on `DrivingLicense.Person_ID`. There are other such mistakes, and a lot of typos like `DrivingLice_ID` instead of `DrivingLicence_ID`. I think you understand the basic concepts of joins, but there are just a lot of tiny mistakes which you need to clear up yourself. Make sure you use a tool which clearly shows error messages, so you are not left wondering whether you have 0 rows or just a syntax error.

Comment: I'm sorry, i made rookie mistakes while editing my post to post a nice overview. @xQbert, thank you for your tip, i understand what you are saying. I've been reading about FULL OUTER JOINS, i see i have to emulate them, but i keep getting the error my column out of tables are not the same, that is correct, they are not, just like the column names are not the same. I've tried with UNION between the different SELECT methodes, but still getting the same error.

Comment: "WHERE x=y AND x=y"? This shouldn't be there.

Comment: David, sorry, that was an example that i use a WHERE statement.

Comment: SELECT * with joins is bad practice

Comment: In your question you state that you want the vehicles a person on and if he is permitted to drive that vehicle. In a comment at xQbert's answer you state that you want also all vehicletypes a person is permitted to drive? Which one is it? If it's the second one then please edit your question.

Comment: @Gervs I'm sorry i will rephrase this: I have made 2 search fields, i am searching on a unique value from the person (A social number) and on a license plate. So: Person A, owns Car A. If there is a match, i want to show some vehicle information, but i also want to check if the person is allowed to drive the vehicle, based on the person's license type and the vehicle type. (I have made another query which shows all the vehicles the person owns, that is no problem, I've fixed that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've placed the tables in a more logic other:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.name,
    v.VehicleType,
    v.make,
    v.model,
    CASE
       WHEN ltvt.VehicleType_ID =  v.VehicleType_ID THEN 1
       ELSE 0
    END allowed
FROM
    Person p
JOIN
    Vehicles v
    ON p.ID = v.person_id
LEFT JOIN
    DrivingLicense dl
    ON p.ID = dl.Person_ID
LEFT JOIN
    DrivingLicenseLicenceType dlt
    ON dl.ID = dlt.DrivingLicense_ID
LEFT JOIN
    LicenseTypes lt
    ON dlt.LicenseType_ID = lt.ID
LEFT JOIN
    LicenseTypeVehicleTypes ltvt
    ON dlt.LicenseType_ID = ltvt.LicenseType_ID
    AND ltvt.VehicleType_ID = v.VehicleType_ID
    AND dl.ExpiryDate >= CURRENT_DATE
```

This will result in all persons with the vehicles they own.
By adding some conditions to the last left join you can determine if driving a certain vehicle is permitted.
If you want a specific person and/or a specific vehicle just add a WHERE clause

**Update**

> John has 1 drivers license, which has 2 licensetypes: B and AM. Both B and AM Licensetypes are connected to to the VehicleType: Scooter. Only Licensetype B, is connected to my VehicleType: Familywagon, when i change the vehicletype from Scooter to Familywagon, my value shows 0, that i'm not allowed to drive this vehicle

This has to do with the join logic and the datamodel.
Because driving license is related to person and not directly to a vehicle, with the left join a vehicletype will have as many entries as the number of vehicletypes a licensetype has.

In your situation John's Familywagon will apear twice in the result, once for the scooter part of the license type (with which he isn't allowed to drive a car), and once for Familywagon part (with which he is allowed to drive a car).

This can be avoided by creating a virtual table with a subquery with the distinct vehicletypes a person is allowed to drive.

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    v.VehicleType_ID,
    v.make,
    v.model,
    CASE
        WHEN dls.VehicleType_ID =  v.VehicleType_ID THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END allowed
FROM
    Person p
JOIN
    Vehicles v
    ON p.ID = v.Person_ID
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        dl.Person_ID,
        ltvt.VehicleType_ID
    FROM
        DrivingLicense dl       
    JOIN
        DrivingLicenseLicenseTypes dlt
        ON dl.ID = dlt.DrivingLicense_ID
    JOIN
        LicenseTypes lt
        ON dlt.LicenseType_ID = lt.ID
    JOIN
        LicenseTypeVehicleTypes ltvt
        ON dlt.LicenseType_ID = ltvt.LicenseType_ID
    WHERE
        dl.ExpiryDate >= CURRENT_DATE
    ) dls
    ON p.ID = dls.Person_ID
        AND dls.VehicleType_ID =  v.VehicleType_ID
```

Note that it might be wise to include the persons table in the subquery, if you want information about a certain person, so you can narrow down the number of results from the subquery.

Comment: Wow, thanks, you have cleared up my mind.. I think i get it, i'm adding soin JOINS to call up the color of the vehicle from another table etc. But i can do that. I just have 1 more question, can i echo the value of "allowed" in PHP? So if the person is valid to drive the vehicle, echo 1, else echo 0?

Comment: I have 1 more issue i can't seem to solve, everything works perfect except 1 thing: I have "John" who has a vehicle, which is a scooter. John has 1 drivers license, which has 2 licensetypes: B and AM. Both B and AM Licensetypes are connected to to the VehicleType: Scooter. Only Licensetype B, is connected to my VehicleType: Familywagon, when i change the vehicletype from Scooter to Familywagon, my value shows 0, that i'm not allowed to drive this vehicle.. Except, my LiceneType DOES match the VehicleType. Any idea?

Comment: You've marked the other answer as the correct answer so the question is solved?

Comment: That was a mistake, as the other answer is very helpfull too, your answer brings me exactly to the situation i wanted to create! I have marked your answer as the corrent answer. But i am still struggling with my above comment, have you got any clue? In the meanwhile i'm try out some things too, but i'm not sure what to edit.

Comment: Thank you, i get it, like you said the driver license is related to the person, i see where you are pointing at.. Allright i'm gonna fix this, i get the logic behind this.. I will add another AND at the end of the query, to check the date of the driver license, because this hasn't to be in the subquery, i undestand.. 1 more (last) question (sorry), i have made an extra table for my vehicle types, so i want to join: Vehicle.Type VehicleType.ID, is it best to make another subquery for that? I did the same with the gender for my person.. I want to join my Person.Gender to Gender.ID.

Comment: I can't edit above comment, i typed Vehicle.Type, but i mean Vehicle.Model en VehicleModel.ID

Comment: If there's no m-n relationship between Vehicles and Models, a join will do

Answer (score 1):

- INNER JOIN: ONLY Return data that's in BOTH
- LEFT JOIN: ALWAYS Return data in first table, and then only related data in second
- RIGHT JOIN: Always return data from second table and then only related data form 
  first.
- FULL OUTER: Always Return all data from all tables and align
  them when they relate. (not available in mySQL)
- CROSS JOIN: Return all data from first table and relate it to all data in the second table, no relationships.... so if 2 records are in first table and 5 in second... total result would be 10 records.

So lets try...

```
SELECT * 
FROM LicenseTypes LT
LEFT JOIN LicenseTypeVehicleTypes LTVH
 on LTVH.LicenseType_ID = LT.ID
LEFT JOIN DrivingLIcense DL
 on DL.ID = DLLT.DrivingLicense_ID
LEFT JOIN Person P
 on P.ID = DL.Person_ID
LEFT JOIN LicenseTypeVehicleTypes LTVT
 on LTVT.LicenseType_ID = LT.ID
LEFT JOIN VehicleTypes VT
 on VT.ID = LTVT.VehicleType_ID
LEFT JOIN Vehicles V
 on V.ID = VT.ID
WHere P.Name = 'Person1' and V.ID = 'VIN'
```

If a Person1 has a license Type 'X' and 'VIN' has License Type 'X'
then a record will show.
If however, it doesn't no records will return.

if no where clause is provided, all license types will be returned along with the people and vehciles
which make use of those license types.

No people or vehicles will be returned if they are not associated to a specific license type.
If you need the people as well, then we would have to union the above query with one that starts
at person and union one that starts with vehicle.

Comment: Tagged with MySQL, which doesn't support full outer joins

Comment: I am getting: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULL OUTER JOIN, possibly because of MySQL yes. Any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: No it will not work... middle tables with data not in outer tables would get excluded in results. You really need to understand the carnality of the data and if it's optional.  All vehicles may not have people and all people may not be assigned to cars then I think we could do it by using the correct left and right joins.  People, LicenseTypes and Vehicles appear to be the three primary tables.  In english explain the desired results.  Do you want all license types and a list of people and vehicles?

Comment: - A person can have multiple vehicles - A Person has 1 drivers license, which can contain multiple licensetypes. - A Vehicle can have 1 owner - A Vehicle only can have 1 type. - 1 Licentype may let you drive multiple vehicles. I want to accomplish a list that shows me: Name of the person, with the license he owns, showing the licensetype. Then i want to show the Vehicle, with the vehicle type and what driver license it requires. Lets say, all persons have a vehicle, and all vehicles have an owner.

Comment: Your table structure as listed doesn't list owners.  there is no person_ID on vehicles table.   What it shows is people and the types of licensees they have and vehicles and types of licenses they have.  I don't see where it lists vehicles tied to persons.

Comment: Apologize, you are totally right.. I have added Person_ID in my scheme (as it is in my database structure)..

Comment: @xQbert Thank you for your Edit, i'm getting results now, but i don't really understand this JOIN: LEFT JOIN DrivingLIcense DL
 on DL.ID = DLLT.DrivingLicense_ID , im Joining DL, but the = value, is pointing to a table i haven't joined before. Is this correct?

Comment: Does a person always have a driving license?

Comment: @Gervs In this case, yes.

Comment: Right now the following query gives me double results: SELECT * 
FROM RijbewijsTypes
LEFT JOIN RijbewijstypeVoertuigtype ON RijbewijstypeVoertuigtype.RijbewijstypeID = RijbewijsTypes.ID
LEFT JOIN RijbewijsRijbewijsType ON RijbewijsRijbewijsType.RijbewijstypeID
LEFT JOIN Rijbewijs ON Rijbewijs.ID = RijbewijsRijbewijsType.RijbewijsID
LEFT JOIN Persoon ON Persoon.ID = Rijbewijs.PersoonID
LEFT JOIN Voertuig ON Voertuig.PersoonID = Persoon.ID
LEFT JOIN Merk ON Merk.ID = Voertuig.Merk
LEFT JOIN Type ON Merk.Type = Type.ID
WHERE Persoon.BSNNummer =  '20230913'
AND Voertuig.Kenteken =  'NH-UN-78'